# Is it appropriate to reduce the sentence in this way?

Tags: ellipsis, legalese, past-participles, reflexive-pronouns

Can I say this sentence in this way:

> The document which is to be signed by me is to be reviewed by the Manager and to be signed by the General Director.
>   ⇒
>   The document to be signed by me to be reviewed by the Manager and signed by the General Director.

1) I did the reduction as per the rule which says that in contracts and other business documents the verbs "is" and "are" are removed, and they were an example of removing according to which I made the reduction: 
"The bill of lading to be considered (=is to be considered) proof of the date of shipment"

2) Both sentences written by me may content grammar mistakes, if so please correct errors in both of them.

Comment: No, we would connect the clauses with **and**: .... to be signed by me and reviewed by the manager and signed by the General Director".  You can eliminate the repeated "to be".

Comment: Also, in no contract would we find "The bill of lading to be considered proof of the date of shipment" as a separate sentence (because it is only a fragment) though we might find it as an adjunct: "...shall produce a bill of lading, said bill of lading to be considered proof of the date of shipment".

Comment: So, the best way to say this sentence is "The document to be signed by me and reviwed by the manager and signed by the General Director', right?

Comment: No. That is not a *sentence* but a noun-phrase. It lacks a tensed verb.  **signed**, **reviewed** are past-participles.  They are not tensed verbs. Those are passive constructions: to be signed, to be reviewed and they modify the nouns.

Comment: A *sentence*  requires a predicate.

Comment: How can I say one sentence, with use of modal verb "to be to", where are: the document which is needed to be signed by me, then it is needed to be reviewed by the manager, and then it is neeeded to be signed by the General Director? Please write down your variant how it would be possible from your point of view.

Comment: The verb phrase **is to be + {past participle}** has the modal force of **must**: *This medicine **is to be taken** once a day.* To use your example: *This document is to be signed by me, reviewed by the Manager, and then signed by the General Director.*

Answer (score 1):

Consider this sentence:

> The wood is to be painted.

Now consider this legalistic sentence, where we drop the verb-to-be:

> The specification calls for wood, *said wood to be painted*.

The main clause must always have an explicit tensed verb:

> The specification *calls* for wood...

whereas an adjunct does not:

> ... said wood to be painted.

There, **said** is not a tensed verb but an adjective that means "the aforementioned".

So we cannot say:

> The bill of lading to be considered proof of the date of
>   shipment.<sup>ungrammatical, lacks a tensed verb</sup>

But we can say:

> The shipper must produce a bill of lading, *said bill of lading to be
>    considered proof of the date of shipment*.